# OpenMP lock not protecting apparently?

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, openmp

I wrote a sequential program and now I want to write a parallel version of it. I though of using OpenMP.
I have an in.dat file containing some dummy Lorem Ipsum text, and I have two functions: one counts the occurence of every letter as an initial in the text (`statistics_on_initials`), and the other counts the number of words and characters in the text (`statistics_on_counts`).
I have the very same functions in my sequential program, so I know what the results should be, but this parallel version will return different results on each execution. I tried using both `atomic`'s and `omp_lock`'s, but it seems like they don't protect the shared variables,
e.g. `words` in the second function will never reach the actual value that is being returned in the sequential version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define LINESIZE 300
#define ROWSIZE 1000 


void read_text(char text[][LINESIZE], int *n) {

    FILE * fp;
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen("in.dat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error reading input file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(text[i], LINESIZE, fp)) 
    {
        text[i][strlen(text[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    (*n) = i;
    fclose(fp);
}

void write_text(char text[][LINESIZE], int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", text[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void statistics_on_initials(char text[][LINESIZE], int n, int thread_count) {

    int initials[26] = {0};

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count) \
        default(none) shared(text, n, initials, thread_count) schedule(static, n/thread_count)
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int x;
        char line[LINESIZE];
        strcpy(line, text[i]);
        char *next;
        next = strtok(line," ,.-;?!");
        while (next != NULL) {
            if (next[0] >= 'a' && next[0] <= 'z') {
                x = next[0] - 'a';
                initials[x]++;
            }
            if (next[0] >='A' && next[0] <= 'Z') {
                x = next[0] - 'A';
                initials[x]++;
            }
            next = strtok(NULL," ,.-;?!");
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        printf("Occurence of initial %c is %d\n", i + 'a', initials[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void statistics_on_counts(char text[][LINESIZE], int n, int thread_count) {
    int words = 0, characters = 0;

    omp_lock_t wordslock, chlock;
    omp_init_lock(&wordslock);
    omp_init_lock(&chlock);

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count) \
        default(none) shared(text, n, words, characters, thread_count, wordslock, chlock) schedule(static, n/thread_count)
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("this is line %d\n", i);
        char line[LINESIZE];
        strcpy(line, text[i]);
        char *next;
        next = strtok(line," ,.-;?!");
        while (next != NULL) {
            omp_set_lock(&wordslock);
            words++;
            omp_unset_lock(&wordslock);
            if ((next[0] >= 'a' && next[0] <= 'z') || (next[0] >='A' && next[0] <= 'Z')) {
                for (int j=0; j<strlen(next); j++) {
                    omp_set_lock(&chlock);
                    characters++;
                    omp_unset_lock(&chlock);
                }
            }
            next = strtok(NULL," ,.-;?!");
        }
    }

    omp_destroy_lock(&chlock);
    omp_destroy_lock(&wordslock);

    printf("There are:\n%d lines\n%d words and\n%d characters in the text.\n\n", n, words, characters);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    char text[ROWSIZE][LINESIZE];
    int n;
    int thread_count = 8;
    read_text(text, &n);
    write_text(text, n);
    statistics_on_initials(text, n, thread_count);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time spent: %f\n", time_spent);
}
```

Neither of the two functions calculate the correct results.
Also, how can I protect a whole array `initials[]` while still trying to keep the program effective when not even the `lock` seems to work?

Comment: `if (next[0] >= 'a' && next[0] <= 'z')` should be `if (islower(next[0]))...`, `if (next[0] >='A' && next[0] <= 'Z')` should be `if (isupper(next[0]))...`.  Letters are not guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: All these variables where your accumulate your results must be declared `reduction(+:)`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think OP is assuming that it will be ASCII otherwise x = next[0] - 'a'; would not work either

Comment: What @Gilles says about the reduction + `strtok()` is not reentrant.